# UPSERT - Is there a better alternative to MERGE or @@rowcount?

Tags: sql-server-2008, upsert

I was wondering if you have encountered a T-SQL command similar to the concept of UPSERT?  Performing INSERT|UPDATE operations using options (1) or (2) seems overly complex and error prone.

**OBJECTIVE**

To ensure that the desired record (in this case employee_id 1) is up-to-date WITHOUT having to having to essentially write the same query twice.

**CONTEXT**

- table name: employee
- employee id: has a primary key, and identity proerty is set to true

**OPTIONS**

1. execute a SQL UPDATE... check @@rowcount = 0 and @@error = 0... execute SQL INSERT if required

   - con: you effectively have to write the same query twice, once as an
     insert, once as an update
   - con: more code = more time typing
   - con: more code = more room for error

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106717/how-to-implement-a-conditional-upsert-stored-procedure "Update using @@rowcount"

2. execute a SQL MERGE

   - con: you effectively have to write the same query twice, once as an insert, once as an update
   - con: more code = more time typing
   - con: more code = more room for error

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx "T-SQL Merge"

3. execute a SQL UPSERT (feature does not exist)

   - pro: you define the data-to-table relationship once (let SQL Server worry about whether or not it is an INSERT or an UPDATE)
   - pro: less code = faster implementation
   - pro: less code = lower probability

**UPSERT EXAMPLE**

UPSERT employeee (employee_id, employee_number, job_title, first_name, middle_name, surname,  modified_at)
VALUES (1, '00-124AB37', 'Manager', 'John', 'T', 'Smith', GetDate());

- if employee_id 1 does not exist: MS SQL executes a INSERT statement
- if employee_id 1 exists: MS SQL executes and UPDATE statement

Comment: This seems like a feature request for Microsoft, not something anyone here can help you solve. The solution Microsoft came up with is MERGE. If that is not flexible/powerful enough for you, then you need a different solution which doesn't exist yet.

Comment: In my opinion, `MERGE` is straightforward, flexible, and it is also part of SQL Standard. The real problem with `MERGE` and other `UPSERT` implementations is potential lock escalation or even deadlocks which has nothing to do with syntax.

Comment: If you have a question, feel free to ask it.  As written this is basically a diatribe about `MERGE` implementation in SQL Server.

Comment: Good question - is there essentially an UPSERT statement where the server worries about whether it requires an insert or update. I agree, MERGE doesn't meet what you would logically expect of an implementation of "UPSERT". Given MS chose to implement this way, my question would be: what might have been a shortcoming, or impossible to implement, had they attempted to implement the syntax you (and I) would like?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the simple answer to this is no. `MERGE` was Microsoft's answer to the more convoluted `UPSERT` logic. And you didn't even list the worst approach:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT ... ) > 0
    UPDATE
ELSE
    INSERT
```

I just threw up in my mouth a little typing that, but it's actually the one I see most often.

In any case, if `MERGE` is not flexible or powerful enough for you, I suggest you submit a feature request to Microsoft at http://connect.microsoft.com/sql/ and explain, thoroughly, your business case. As long as you stick to real advantages of your proposed syntax over `MERGE`, you've got my vote. If you hang too much on the "error-prone" part, I'm not as likely to buy in. Why? Because you can fat-finger any statement.

That said, I don't think there's anything anyone here can do for you specifically. You should investigate the potential problems with `MERGE`:

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I looked through the T-SQL documentation on MSDN and couldn't find what I was looking for; just thought I would throw it out there in case I missed something.  While the MERGE statement makes sense in certain situations, I can't help but feel that it is a "sledge hammer to pound in a nail" solution for a simple save operation.  Perhaps I should take of my programmer hat, and put on my DBA Fedora. Thank you for taking the time to share your thoughts.